# RxJS polling + retry using a backoff strategy

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I've been trying to implement my own RxJS operator, so that I can "plug it" to my Angular's HttpClient. I'd like to keep the request ongoing (polling) every X milliseconds, but also in case of errors I'd like to retry the requests using some sort of incremental strategy. Here's a breakdown:

1. Repeat the request over and over again every X milliseconds (polling)
2. In case of error, the request shall be retry every Y milliseconds, but if the request fails again, the milliseconds should double (e.g. first fail 1000ms, second 2000ms, third 4000ms) up until a limit, if this limit is reached, for example 1 minute, then the retry will not increase again and all subsequent retries should wait 1 minute.
3. After a succesful retrying, the retry ms counter should restart, so that the next time it will retry again from Y milliseconds.
4. When performing a request that for whatever reason takes a lot of time to respond, we need to ensure that no other request is fired nor cancelled (I can see a possible use of concatMap here!)

Here's what I have so far:

```
function repeatWithBackoff<T>(delay: number, maxDelay = 60000) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) =>
    timer(0, delay).pipe(
      concatMap(() => {
        return source.pipe(
          retryWhen((attempts) => {
            return attempts.pipe(
              concatMap((attempt, i) => {
                const backoffDelay = Math.min(delay * Math.pow(2, i), maxDelay);
                return timer(backoffDelay);
              })
            );
          })
        );
      })
    );
}
```

And here's how I use it:

```
httpClient.post(...)
  .pipe(repeatWithBackoff(1000, 60000))
  .subscribe((x) => console.log('Result', x));
```

Apparently my code, *kinda works* but the retries are not working properly, I would expect that nothing happens, when the request fails (e.g. no console.log()) but I can see the observable printed to the console.
Also, if someone has a clever idea to simplify the function, I will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern RxJS makes this task simple by using the built-in `retry` and `repeat` operators which accept quite powerful configs.

```
import { pipe, retry, repeat, timer } from 'rxjs'

function pollWithBackoff<T> (delay: number, maxDelay: number): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return pipe(
    retry({
      delay: (_error, i) => {const backoffDelay = Math.min(delay * Math.pow(2, i-1), maxDelay);
      return timer(backoffDelay);}
    }),
    repeat({
      delay
    }),
  )
}
```

See it in [action on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-artvh1?file=index.ts).

Best way to create complex operators is using the `pipe` function. That enables you to compose RxJS operators the same way you would use them in the `.pipe` method. No need to work with the source observable in which you would need to take care of all errors and completions and send them to the output observable.

First, use `retry` operator that accepts a config object, in which you can provide the custom timing function. It is important that you start with the `retry` operator, because we want the backoff to restart each time the request errors. *Note: I don't know why, but it appears that the error index in `i` starts with 1.*

Now you have the logic "take this request and retry with exponential backoff". After that, add `repeat` operator which again accepts a config object with a `delay`. That makes sure that the previous logic repeats. Because we already took care of the retries, using the `repeat` operator stays simple and repeats only once a successful request is made.

See [retry documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/retry), [repeat documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/repeat) for more info on the config objects.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this approach is way cleaner. I copied your solution to a simplified stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/polling-rxjs-007-fy8xhr
Clicking the button makes the request to repeat, but after you disable the network (to generate an Error) I can still see the previous successful response being logged to the console. I'd expect a "silent" retry with nothing being logged until we succeed again (e.g. network restored)

Comment: I see the same problem when using DevTool. Seems to me that stackblitz monkey patches some network internals, though, because when I pull out my LAN cable and disable WiFi, the behaviour is as described in the answer and same as using a `of(value)` as source observable. Good to know, though, about the stackblitz issue.